# How many times does $f= z^3+\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$ wind around $0$ along the circle of radius $2$ centered at $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How many times does $f= z^3+\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$ wind around $0$ along the circle of radius $2$ centered at $0$?

I need to compute the integral of $\frac{f'}{f}$ along $|z|=2$, how to compute it?

Comment: $f$ doesn't wind around $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at when the function is defined and if it is holomorphic. Then look at the singularities (for example where the denominator becomes zero). Then based on this, use Cauchy's residue formula to compute the residue at these singularities (or use Laurent series) and finally usa Cauchy's Residue Theorem to evaluate the integral

Comment: But how do you actually compute this probelm

Comment: @koch By the argument principle, we have that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'}{f} = \#\text{Zeros}-\#\text{Poles}$ (counted with multiplicity), so will be $3-2 = 1$.  It follows that $\int_C\frac{f'}{f} = 2\pi i$.  For a reference see [page 90](https://www.fing.edu.uy/~cerminar/Complex_Analysis.pdf).

Comment: $0$ is not a zero of this function though.